# check bunches of data

Tags: excel, vba, forms, autofill, auto

I have got a lot of different data which needs to be compared on a site. I explain it deeply

[image: an example of the data]

I have to go to a website paste a1 on box1 paste b1 on box2 and paste c1 on box3 of a site the site has recaptcha (I'm not asking if I'm able to bypass or not I know I will have to solve it myself so in that case my script, application or whatever would have to wait there for me to solve the captcha as [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMIPy.png) then this will lead to a new page with a  [particular piece of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCHCy.png) in which case the macro app or whatever should post in d1 something like INVALID then it needs to restart but this time take column 2 i.e. a2 b2 c2 d2 I have been reading that best way to achieve this would be  doing it in VBA and I have tried to follow tutorials and so on but I don't seem to quite understand it well.

what I have tried is:

```
Sub ListaNominal()
    
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/"
    
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    Set doc = IE.document
    IE.document.getElementById("claveElector").Value = GTLPAL73052511H600
    doc.getElementById("numeroEmision").Value = 2
    doc.getElementById("ocr").Value = 1121035022017#
    MsgBox "Click to go on", , "Example"
    
    
    Set element = doc.getElementsByClassName("col-xs-6 col-sm-8 table-responsive")("VALIDA")
    
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("d1").Value = element
    
End Sub
```

but doesn't seem to work even with a hardcoded value. A friend of mine told me that maybe VBA would be so difficult that I should try CSV file along with Autofill Chrome app, but I don't seem to understand how to do this any help would be appreciated

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without a URL or all of the relevant HTML.

Comment: https://listanominal.ine.mx/scpln/ at the start everything goes fine the problem comes after i click on "continue" it kinda sends more values than its supposed to as it returns problem with the captcha and with a mistake made in a value wich i know its the second one because it needs to be "02" instead of a simple2 alright just noticed that i was making a mistake by not adding the quotations

doc.getElementById("numeroEmision").Value = "02"

form filling is working fine however captcha i solve becomes wrong answered now and still trying the "break" - > "resume thing to work